# Execute EXE as JPG

Tags: image, cmd, executable, steganography

I've made a simple program in Visual Basic, then gave it JPG extension and set it up to be run from shortcut with command line `cmd.exe /c my_program.jpg`, according to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y4A_BtxJJb4) and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-3UZn8dN6MQ) guides.

Everything is fine so far, but I'd like to run my program from an image without command prompt opening.

I know that such thing is possible, because I can run programs from PDF, RTF or Word documents because most of PDF files have JS API features, and Microsoft Office documents have VBA and macro support. Maybe some steganography thingamajig can do the trick?

Comment: ??!!?! Convert EXE file to JPG? This must be the joke of the century. Sure, executable files are images... but not THOSE kind of images! =)

Comment: See this: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/81677/how-is-it-possible-to-embed-executable-code-in-an-image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is hard to believe, but it's actually true. My investigation (with Rohitab API Monitor) shows that upon finding the file, `cmd.exe` first invokes `CreateProcessW` - *and only if that fails* (in this case, with error 193 == `ERROR_BAD_EXE_FORMAT`), tries `ShellExecuteW`.

This behavior is actually documented in [KB811528 - Command Prompt (Cmd.exe) Runs Files That Do Not Have Executable File Name Extensions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/811528). Sure, the article mentions in passing that this can lead to execution of viruses (as if it's nothing special).

This doesn't apply to Windows Explorer/`shell32` dialogs/most other programs that *open files* - since they invoke `ShellExecute` right away. But this does generally apply to programs that *execute command lines* with `system` or `CreateProcess`! (Do you remember processes like `setup.tmp` during InstallShield-based installations? They are examples.)

Not all programs that run arbitrary commands are affected. E.g. Total Commander is not: it calls `ShellExecute` even for command lines.

---

Now, regarding you specific question. The 2nd guide actually showcases an *exploit* (assuming it's not just a scam) - the author specially crafts the image to exploit some vulnerability in Windows Photo Gallery (that probably has been patched by now) to make it execute the contained code. This isn't supposed to be normally possible.

So, you have two options:

1. Launch your program through another program (with shortcut or otherwise),
   but replace `cmd` with something that doesn't create a console window. `wscript` comes to mind.
2. Use some "intelligent" image format that's supposed to contain executable code. I'm not aware of any *image* ones - after all, images are supposed to contain pictures, not code!

   - There are, of course, more than a few *compound*/*"intelligent"* formats (of which you named a few). Yet, they tend to impose strict limitations on when code inside them can be invoked and what it is allowed to do.
     I'll have you know that these limitations were introduced *specifically as a response* to others doing what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I have trouble believing that, given what you said.

CMD will execute any image file (that's a program file like an exe - nothing to do with pictures at all) that has a recognised executable extension or has an unknown extension. jpg are known as a document type file, so they are opened as a document by Windows Photo Gallery. Explorer won't execute a unknown extension. Both CMD and Explorer uses Explorer's file extensions database to work out how to open document files.

So you need to explain why it works on your computer when it won't work on a standard configured Windows computer.

Comment: On Windows XP in vmware virtual PC according to this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y4A_BtxJJb4 and this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-3UZn8dN6MQ