# Trying to open a python script from another python script using Popen throws Windows Error

Tags: python, popen

I am trying to open a python script from another python script using Popen in Python 2.7.

The two scripts are:

**child.py**: Takes 5 ints one by one and waits some time and prints its square

```
    import time
    for i in range(5):
        value = int(raw_input('Enter an integer: '))
        time.sleep(2)
        print "Its square is ", value*value
```

**parent.py**: Opens child.py and writes 5 ints to its stdin and prints its stdout

```
    import subprocess, time

    # following is the line of interest
    child_program = subprocess.Popen("child.py", 
                                     stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                     stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

    for i in range(5):
        child_program.stdin.write(str(i)+"\n")
        child_program.stdin.flush()
        a = child_program.stdout.readline()
        print [a]  # I put it in list just to see exact format
```

The following are the **other substitutions** that I used for the first argument of Popen constructor in parent.py after seeing many similar question in stackoverflow

```
    "./child.py": Same WindowsError is produced
    <full path>:  Same WindowsError is produced
    ["python", "child.py"]: Did not raise error but opened python (useless)
```

**The WindowsError produced is:**

```
    WindowsError: [Error 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to Specify the type of file you are trying to open as a subprocess

```
 child_program = subprocess.Popen(['executable','child.py'], 
                                 stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                                 stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                 stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

This should resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Python interpreter setup to handle *.py files, then you can just set `shell=True` in your Popen constructor:

```
child_program = subprocess.Popen("child.py",
                                 shell=True,
                                 stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                                 stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                 stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

**As others have pointed out, this method comes with a security warning**, so you'd have to take care that the arguments you pass to Popen aren't maliciously constructed (for instance, if you're getting some of your arguments from user input): https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#security-considerations

Otherwise, you'll need to tell Popen to use a Python executable to load the file, like this:

```
import sys

child_program = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "child.py"],
                                 stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                                 stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                 stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

In this context, `sys.executable` will resolve to the full path of the Python binary that was used to launch your parent script.

Comment: If you need shell=True, look for something better. Please recognize this is a security risk!

Answer (score 0):

`Popen` with the default `shell=False` delegates to `CreateProcess` in Windows as [its docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html?highlight=popen#subprocess.Popen) say. That API function can only run executable files (regardless of their extension).

You need to either

- add [the path to the interpreter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589711/find-full-path-of-python-interpreter) as the leading argument
- use machinery that would delegate to `ShellExecute` that would run a command line like above accoring to the file type association. E.g. specify `shell=True` (heed the security warnings in the doc) because [`cmd.exe` falls back to `ShellExecute` for non-executable files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31855240/execute-exe-as-jpg/31861241?s=1%7C7.0418#31861241).